# A combinatorics puzzle related to Stars and bars problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem goes like: 
A store sells 11 different flavors of ice cream. In how many ways can a customer choose 6 ice cream cones, not necessarily of different flavors?

I tried thinking for 2 days then I gave up and seen solution. The answer was somewhat connected to Stars and bars problem. The question is how can this problem be connected to Stars and bars puzzle? I am not able to see any connection of this puzzle to the problem. For eg: Stars and bars puzzle requires identical object to be distributed in boxes which is not case here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) technique is the right tool here. Note that you have to count the non-negative integer solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{11}=6$$
where $x_i$ is the number of icecreams taken from the "box" containing "identical" icecreams all of the $i$-th flavour.

Can you take it from here? What is the final answer?